# 403 Forbidden when making Golang POST

Tags: go, http-status-code-403

I have a REST endpoint provided by a Java Spring Boot app that I am trying to hit with a simple Go (go1.8 darwin/amd64) program.  I have tried to hit it in 2 separate ways:

```
const (
    LOCAL_BASE         = "http://localhost:11400"
    ADD_FUNDS_ENDPOINT = "/sub-accounts/%d/add-funds"
)

type InputArgumentsJson struct {
    Amount           float64 `json:"amount"`
    BufferAmount     float64 `json:"bufferAmount"`
    FromSubAccountID int     `json:"fromSubAccountId"`
}

...

// set up json body
inputArguments := &InputArgumentsJson{Amount: 1100, BufferAmount: 0,
    FromSubAccountID: spendFundId}
bytes := new(bytes.Buffer)
json.NewEncoder(bytes).Encode(inputArguments)

// set up the url to call
endpoint := fmt.Sprintf(ADD_FUNDS_ENDPOINT, billSetAsideId)
url := LOCAL_BASE + endpoint

client := &http.Client{}

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("ERROR WHILE BUILDING REQUEST")
    fmt.Println(err)
}

req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("ERROR WHILE MAKING REQUEST")
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(resp)
```

and:

```
resp, err := http.Post(url, "application/json; charset=utf-8", bytes)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("ERROR WHILE MAKING REQUEST")
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(resp)
```

I added a print out to see if the URL and JSON body were right and they appeared to be:

```
fmt.Printf("\nMaking request to %s with:\n %s\n", url, bytes)
```

printed out

```
Making request to http://localhost:11400/sub-accounts/167/add-funds with:
{"amount":1100,"bufferAmount":0,"fromSubAccountId":166}
```

but I am getting a 403 Forbidden when running it.

I can hit this endpoint without fail using both Postman and the following Curl command:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"amount":1100,"bufferAmount":0,"fromSubAccountId":166}' http://localhost:11400/sub-accounts/167/add-funds`

Does anyone have any thoughts on what I may be missing here?  To add further to the intrigue I can successfully hit a different GET endpoint from the Go program.

Thanks in advance!

*Edited to show that I was catching the errors and the surrounding logic for creating the URL and JSON body*

Comment: Try to catch your error first, `resp, err := client.Do(req)`, on both your request and response.

Comment: I actually do catch them that way and then have `if err != nil` to print it out, but nothing gets caught.  I left that off for brevity because the server clearly is responding, but with a 403.

Answer (score 0):

You did not show what `bytes` is but that's most probably the problem: both `NewRequest` and `Post` take an `io.Reader` and read the body from that reader. This reading typically can happen only once (think of a stream). When you `fmt.Printf("%s")` the `io.Reader` this printing will consume the content (most probably by invoking a String() method) and the actual request is done with an *empty* body.

Always show whole code. And do not try to read twice from an io.Reader.

Comment: That is a good thought, but it does it whether or not I print the bytes.  I edited my code to show everything.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there are 2 Go apps and runs on a different host, which results a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) problem. Consider adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` at your service with your client's host.

`w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`

You can change `*` with specified hostname which your client application runs.

Comment: The server is actually a Java Spring Boot App.  The strange thing is that I get the same result when it is on my localhost or if I deploy the Spring Boot app to AWS.  In either case the Go app running locally gets a 403 while Curl and Postman can hit the endpoint successfully regardless of where it is running from. Also wouldn't the CORS issue show up in GET requests as well as POST requests?  I can successfully do a GET with my Go program, just not a POST.

Comment: Can you log the request/response header both using Go and Curl?

Comment: It wasn't a CORS issue, but your answer got me to look more carefully at the server where I discovered the problem.  My Go app was fine all along, but the Java app was a bit wonky.

Answer (score 0):

OMG....I just found the problem.  It turned out that it was failing (as I was expecting), but it was erroneously returning it as a 403 rather than a 400.  Ugh...sometimes when you stare at something for a long time the obvious things completely escape notice.

Answer (score 0):

you should set User-Agent in request header

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, urlString, nil)
req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36")
```